# Check if List<List<string>> contains a string

Tags: c#, string, linq, list, contains

How can I check if any `List<string>`s in a `List` contain a given string? I know how to do this with a loop, but is there a way with LINQ/in one line?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
if (lists.Any(sublist => sublist.Contains(str)))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var t=lists.SelectMany(f=>f).Contains("str");
```

full sample :

```
var lists = new List<List<string>>();

lists.Add(new List<string>(){"a","b"});
lists.Add(new List<string>(){"b","2"});
lists.Add(new List<string>(){"c","5"});
lists.Add(new List<string>(){"d","7"});

var t=lists.SelectMany(f=>f);

t.Dump();
```

[image]

```
if (t.Contains("k")) 
  Console.WriteLine ("yes") ;
else 
  Console.WriteLine ("no");
```

result

```
no
```

p.s.

ofcourse - this can be shorten to :

```
if (lists.SelectMany(f=>f).Contains("k"))...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
bool ifExists = list.Any(x => x.Contains(yourString));
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to add to existing answers, given your lists are sorted and large, `BinarySearch` may yield faster than `Contains` or `Any`.